# Event `selectstart` is not working on `input` field

Tags: javascript, html, angular, events

I have a problem with angular directive. I have prepared a simple project on stackblitz [Project](https://stackblitz.com/github/rejkid/TestBasicMaterialTable).
Basically I have noticed that HTML `input` control receives `select` events but never receives `selectstart` events.
Similarly `label` control receives `selectstart` events but never receives `select` events.
You can check it either by watching my debug log output or setting breakpoints in the debugger.

Is this by design or a bug in angular?

The `Directive` (containing only event handler) and `html template` look like this:

*Directive*:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
  selector: '[appDateInput]',
  })

export class DateInputDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    console.log("S:" + this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart
      + " E:" + this.el.nativeElement.selectionEnd
    );
  }

  @HostListener('selectstart', ['$event'])
  onSelectStart(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    //event.preventDefault();
    console.log("onSelectStart called");
    console.log("S:" + this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart
      + " E:" + this.el.nativeElement.selectionEnd
    );
  }
  @HostListener('select', ['$event'])
  onSelect(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    //event.preventDefault();
    console.log("onSelect called");
    console.log("S:" + this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart
      + " E:" + this.el.nativeElement.selectionEnd
    );
  }
  @HostListener('selectionchange', ['$event'])
  onSelectionChange(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    //event.preventDefault();
    console.log("onSelectionChange called");
    console.log("S:" + this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart
      + " E:" + this.el.nativeElement.selectionEnd
    );
  }
}
```

*HTML template:*

```
<label appDateInput>Selection test</label>

<form>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" appDateInput><br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Please put a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) *directly in your question*. Don't just point us to code linked to another website. Code on that site might change or disappear over time, leaving the question here without any context for future readers. Your question becomes much easier to answer when the code you want help with is actually in the question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/77241727/edit) and click the button in the toolbar that looks like `[<>]` to add a code snippet to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected, [selectstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/selectstart_event) belongs to the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection), which concerns the "usual" DOM nodes, while [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select_event) is only for input form elements (`<input>`, `<textarea>`). Unfortunate as this is, they're separate and mutually exclusive APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried to use `selectstart` in `input` element to disable the selection (just my requirements I have) - so that will not work will it?

Comment: That would be its own question, but no `selectstart` isn't the one you want, instead try `selectionchange` which, for inputs isn't very well supported elsewhere than in Firefox, so we need some shenanigans around to do what you want (if I understood it correctly): https://jsfiddle.net/yrd8steb/

Comment: @janci try using pointer events none

Comment: or use `ngModel` directive to bind the input value to a variable in your component

Comment: @Afzal K. What are pointer events none please?

Comment: @janci that's a CSS rule which will prevent pointer events (mouse etc.), but it will also prevent focusing through these means, and will not prevent selection through keyboard. A very bad idea IMO.

Comment: And regarding the `ngModel` proposition, while I'm not into angular, I doubt they will rerender at each selection change, and the value is only very poorly related to your issue.

Comment: @Kaiido Your example is exactly what I want - I am trying to port it to angular but without any success. Again my handler `selectionchange`is never called. Should it be? Or this is again the same problem you have described earlier?

Comment: @janci what is your end goal ?, pointer enter method is workable via additional JS, but that was just a suggestion

Comment: `selectionchange` unfortunately has to be attached on the `document` in Chrome and Safari, that might be your issue. But once again, this warrants its own question has it is only closely related to that one.

Comment: @Afzal K. I appreciate your suggestion. It just didn't work for me.

Comment: @Kaiido Yep. It works the way you did it - I have attached `selectionchange ` to the document. My solution is now bit hybrid - some implementation is done in angular Directive and some bits are done in component itself - but it works. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you both for helping me. I think I will go with the attaching `selectionchange ` to the document. The only question I have - why do I have to attach it to the document ?

Comment: Because Chrome and Safari still didn't implement that event correctly. See               https://crbug.com/1327098 and https://webkit.org/b/234348